# Compiling 32-bit Program on VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compiler-construction, 32bit-64bit

I've been developing on VC++ 2003 on an XP PC but am now on Windows 7 and bought a cheap legal copy of VS 2008 to continue work on the same project. My product has to continue to run on customers' XP systems, so I'm strictly interested in a 32-bit executable.

The first issue I ran into was the PRJ0003 error "spawning cl.exe". I had to add the path to this file to the VC++ Directories settings (it appears in both a bin\amd64 and bin\x86_amd64 directory, but I don't think it matters output-wise which I use?).

The issue I now have (not counting a tedious cleanup to convert strcpy to strcpy_s, etc.) is that I'm not clear on whether I'm generating a 32-bit or 64-bit exe out of this. My project properties are set to a target of "Win32", so I assume that all is well. Is this correct?

I have read some discussions about this, but it's never quite clear if they are talking about whether the compiler itself is running x64 vs. x86, or whether the compiled code is x64 vs. x86, and how this is differentiated.

So am I doing the right thing to generate a 32-bit, Win32, x-86 program?

Comment: How cheap was it?  Did you just copy the install directory from somebody else's machine?  That certainly would explain PRJ0003.  And the next twenty SO questions you'll start.

Comment: Could be requiring the ATL Server component. VS2008 didn't come with it (it got moved to CodePlex, apparently). But then it wouldn't be complaining about cl.exe would it? [Project Build Error PRJ0003 - Visual Studio 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5cbdh4t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Give me a break, Hans. It was an OEM distribution on Microsoft DVDs with a valid Microsoft product key on the back of the disk envelope. It was only cheap ($100) since it's an older version now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you haven't got a totally messed up installation then in VS2008 it's very hard to accidentally create 64-bit executables with a 32-bit project platform (I've been trying to force it to do so for my own reasons and it always seems to mess up at the link stage).  If however your project uses Makefiles then it's a lot easier to end up with the wrong 32/64 bitness, especially if you are building from the command line.  Generally, unless you have specifically set up a 64-bit project then everything should just be building 32-bit.

Given that it looks like the compiler paths are messed up I would suggest doing a repair of VS2008 and then do Tools -> Import and Export settings -> Reset all settings.  Then check out a clean source tree to ensure you don't have any incorrect build artifacts.

As for the `strcpy_s` fix up, bear in mind that the compiler is giving you a warning rather than an error.  If you don't want to be warned about it then simply set `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` as a preprocessor macro.

Comment: I just build from the IDE, so I'll just go ahead and check the executable as you suggest. I did a full install from the DVD, but will recheck the installation as well.

I understand about the warnings, but might as well take advantage of a useful new feature. I don't really have all that many since I was using CString in most places.

Answer (score 0):

bin\amd64 is the 64-bit compiler for AMD64; bin\x86_amd64 is a x86 cross-compiler for AMD64. If you want a 32-bit executable, the bog-standard compiler is in plain old bin. It's been a while since I used VS2008 but if your target is Win32 I think it should be using the standard 32-bit compiler, not the 64-bit one or the cross-compiler.

If you want to check and make sure, grab [Dependency Walker](http://dependencywalker.com/) and open up your executable in it. If there's a vertical "64" on the module icon in the module tree, then you've built a 64-bit executable; if there is just the plain module icon, then it's 32-bit and you're good.

Comment: Actually the only copies of cl.exe are in the bin subdirectories -- not bin itself. However, I realize that cl.exe is not the actual compiler so maybe it's using the compiler itself in another directory. I'm really not that familiar with VS's structure as it has always "just worked" for me before.

Comment: @gordonwd: I've not used VS2008 in a while but I have it installed on my desktop still. And the compiler toolchain is indeed in bin\ itself. Same for 2005 and 2010. Screeny: http://i.imgur.com/91Fmi.png As for cl.exe itself, you're right, it's not the compiler, but it is the front-end (just as gcc is just a frontend for the actual GCC compilers). c1*.dll and c2.dll are the actual compiler components, and they share the same directory as cl.exe. If you don't have all that in your bin dir, your copy of VS2008 might not be as legit as you think.